# C language: scanf and sscanf expressions

Tags: c, scanf

I've encountered a expressions that go something like this inside scanf and sscanf arguments:

```
sscanf(buffer, "%d,%100[^,]%*c%f", destination_pointer)
```

or

```
scanf("\n%99s", destination);
```

What is the correct way of interpreting these? I know what things like "%s %c %d" are, and also that  the %100 or generally "%number" is the size of the input to be read. But what about the rest? All I can find are basic examples, nothing near this complex. Is there any reference guide?

Comment: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html and https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf are pretty comprehensive.

Answer (score 5):

> What is the correct way to interpreted these?

> sscanf(buffer, "%d,%100[^,]%*c%f", destinantion_pointer)

Is an invalid call. There are 3 conversion specifiers that need an argument - `%d`, `%[]`, `%f`. That means exactly 3 arguments after formatting string are needed, but only one `destinantion_pointer` is provided.

- `%d` - ignore any whitespace characters, read an `int` in base 10
- `,` - read a comma
- `%100[^,]` - read maximum number of 100 characters that are not a comma. Maximum up to 101 bytes (100 characters + null byte) are stored in destination buffer.

  - `%[set]` - reads characters in the set
  - `%[^set]` - reads characters that are not in the set
- `%*c` - ignore one character (a comma, because `%100[^,]` reads up until a comma, or the string has ended, which would make `scanf` return here). Note - ignoring the result of conversion with `*` makes `scanf` *not* increment the return value in the case reading was successful.
- `%f` - ignore any whitespace characters, read a float (in any format - decimal, scientific or hexadecimal)

> scanf("\n%99s", destinantion);

- `\n` - read (and ignore) any number of whitespace characters (whitespace, means anything for that [`isspace()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) returns nonzero, so either space, form feed, line feed, carriage return, tab or vertical tab)
- `%99s` - ignore any leading whitespace characters (`\n` in front of it is useless...), then read up to 99 characters that are not whitespaces (the resulting buffer has to be at least 100 bytes long).